# Using AJAX in wordpress theme

Tags: theme-development, ajax

all

In my theme there is a notification at top.
After user login he can see the notification update.
when click on notification i want to make change in database alert field value 0 to 1.

My ajax call in theme

```
 $("#notifications-button").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost/rupp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data:{action:'MyAjaxFunction'},
        success : function(data){
            $('.message-count').hide();
        },

        });


});
```

and in function.php  file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_MyAjaxFunction','MyAjaxFunction');
function MyAjaxFunction()
{
    global $wpdb;
  echo (int)$user_ID;
  $wpdb->update( $wpdb->wp_frm_items, 
            array( 'alerts' =>  1)
            );
}
```

but it not make any changes in alert fields in db.
is that right way to call theme function using ajax?

Comment: Does your `$wpdb->update()` method work when you're not calling it via ajax?

Comment: No that is the issue .. i tried with just echo also but its not replaying me anything in consol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `$where` parameter to your update statement because it doesn't know which row to update. The `$wpdb->update()` method has no default value for the `$where` argument so you must supply one.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows

Try this:

```
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->wp_frm_items, 
        array( 'alerts' =>  1),
        array( 'user' => get_current_user_id() )
        );
```